# How to get top n rows

Tags: sql

I've never written any SQL search queries and I'm not sure if I'm way off base here. Would this work for the problem below?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY population DESC limit 3;
```

Here's the problem:
Given the following database table, write an SQL query that will return the animal name and food of the three animals with the highest populations.

```
|id |  animal    |  food        |population |
|---|------------|--------------|---------------| 
|35 |  ocelot    |  mouse       |  1200000      | 
|36 |  dingo     |  rabbit      |  16000000     | 
|41 |  capybara  |  grass       |  400000       | 
|52 |  remora    |  blood       |  82000000     | 
|54 |  emu       |  fruit       |  725000       | 
|63 |  gecko     |  insects     |  9000000      | 
|68 |  earwig    |  lettuce     |  420000000    |
```

Comment: Which database are you really using Oracle or MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle 11g or before, you can use `rownum` filter on ordered result from subquery:

```
select *
from (
    Select *
    From Your_table
    Order by population desc
) t where rownum <= 3;
```

In Oracle 12c+, you can use `FETCH FIRST` clause:

```
Select *
From Your_table
Order by population desc
fetch first 3 rows only;
```

In MySQL, you can use `LIMIT`

```
Select *
From Your_table
Order by population desc
limit 3;
```

In SQL server, you can use `TOP`:

```
Select top 3 *
From Your_table
Order by population desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    animal,
    food 
from
    table 
order by
    population DESC
top 3
```

try this ?

Comment: you're ordering in ascending order, not descending. `TOP 3` is not valid MySQL, PL/SQL or T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use TOP method to get your result :

```
SELECT TOP 3 animal,food FROM table order by population DESC
```